# Why did I get +2 reputation after hitting the rep cap?

Tags: bug, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I noticed just now that I got +2 from an upvote on an answer of mine. I'm curious as to why I got reputation points in the first place - I already hit the reputation points cap at 200. Here's an image of my history:

[image]

As you can see, I already got 200 today, with no other things that could allow overage (bounties, accepts). Why did I get +2 reputation points?

Comment: Anything in your recently deleted answer list?

Comment: @RobertLongson Nothing, I have not deleted anything that's been downvoted for months. There was also not a downvote today...

Comment: @RobertLongson Wouldn't that show as "removed" with a something like -15 or -10, etc?

Comment: Can you hit http://stackoverflow.com/reputation and compare the results?

Comment: @rene That's weird. That link says I got 200 today

Comment: that comes from the db, so your profile is a bit off due to caching and/or cache invalidation, or unicorns, or waffles ...

Comment: @rene But I got +202. Did I just get a free +2 then? The db rep shows 8,546 total but I got the +2

Comment: I assume it will be rectified once the reputation job has run again, in 6 to 8 minutes...

Comment: Ok. Seems like this has happened before and it did get corrected. Thanks

Comment: @rene That's not how it works. It doesn't just recalculate all profiles occasionally. Your profile has to have been *scheduled* due to some event happening, like a deletion or undeletion of a post you own. The system then recalculates everyone in the list. This *will* eventually correct itself, just whenever something happens to warrant a recalc.

Comment: @animuson ah, yeah, that sounds like a less resource consuming approach. I assume you can trigger this your self by deleting and undeleting an post?

Comment: It is also possible that you downvoted two answers that got deleted. The reputation you lost by downvoting would then be refunded back to you.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, in fact, I did. I undownvoted after. Could that be the cause?

Comment: Sure. Downvoting an answer (not a question) costs 1 reputation point. If you remove that downvote, or the downvoted answer gets removed, then that point would be returned to you. Not being a moderator, I can't see any private details about your history, so I can only speculate, but this seems like a plausible explanation. It's happened to me in the past.

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah, but the +2 is from an upvote? I downvoted and undownvoted (with rep being returned) but I still get +2 from an upvote when I'm over the cap?

Comment: FYI this +2 came long after the 2 downvote and un-downvotes.