# Puzzling 'By Post' Scoring

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

My [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler?tab=reputation) for today's votes on Stack Overflow is (was transiently) puzzling, and I need <s>3</s> 4 images to explain it (sorry).

The overall view with a bug showing is:

[image]

You can see that the 'Why `"foo\\<NEWLINE>bar"` becomes `"foo\bar"` after "gcc -E"?' question appears at the top with a claim of 16 events.  However, it also appears new the bottom with a claim of 3 events.

Why isn't appearing once?

When I expand the entries, they both show 19 events:

[image]

and:

[image]

Since they're consistent, I'm only puzzled about the split entry — why are there two entries for the single answer to a single question?  (I think it is good that the content is consistent, maybe — though it would be one level less puzzling if one of the expansions showed 3 events and the other 16.)

To add to the confusion — or, more likely, just the unsolveability of the issue — I reloaded the page and the two entries are now combined into one with 19 events.  This is more or less what I would expect — the issue is how did I get the transient 'double entry' display.

[image]

This is in no sense a show-stopper, especially as it seems to happen transiently.  It's just a bit puzzling.

Comment: IIRC, there is a roll-up script that runs not so often, I think Animuson explained that a while ago in a comment. I'll try to find it.

Comment: It might be [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340899/why-did-i-get-2-reputation-after-hitting-the-rep-cap#comment428451_340899)

Comment: @rene: thanks for finding that.  It might be the same general problem.  At least I'm not the only person to have observed oddities along these lines.

Comment: 4 images and **no free-drawn circles**. *That's* what you should be sorry for.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you visit the "reputation" tab the events that have occurred since the last time you visited that tab are highlighted. In your first three images these are the the lines with yellow background.

You are seeing two separate lines for the question 'Why "foo\\<​NEWLINE>bar" becomes "foo\bar" after "gcc -E"?' because three of the upvotes (3 events) on that question occurred prior to the last time you looked at the "reputation" tab. The other 15 upvotes and the accept (16 events) occurred between the last time you visited the reputation tab and this time.  Thus they are highlighted.  The total of the events that are highlighted is the same as the reputation change total displayed in the tab badge:
[image: Reputation tab bagde]

At least the "reputation" and "responses" tags both have tab badges displaying the number changed/added from the last time you looked at that tab. You can see the badges when the page is reloaded at a time when such changes have occurred. Both of those tabs highlight the added events/responses.

From a UI point of view, I would expect that the number of events shown when the line is expanded would match the number of events listed in the summary line. Thus, I would consider that all events are shown under both to be a bug, but it might be a misfeature. However, that is just my opinion about how it should work. I'm not in a position to duplicate this at the moment. I thought I had previously looked at such and seen that the number of expanded events matched each summary line for both the highlighted and non-highlighted summary lines (i.e. that the number of events were different).

Comment: +1 for including a freehand circle in the answer, even though there wasn't one in the question!